# SQL Server query to find parent names of child

Tags: sql-server, join, parent, common-table-expression

i have a table like this

```
ID  Name    Mother  Father
1   Sue     NULL    NULL
2   Ed      NULL    NULL
3   Emma    1       2
4   Jack    1       2
5   Jane    NULL    NULL
6   Bonnie  5       4
7   Bill    5       4
```

and i need output as below

```
ID  Name    Mother  Father
3   Emma    sue     ed
4   jack    sue     ed
6   bonnie  jane    jack
7   bill    jane    jack
```

i have tried writing query with join n cte but couldnt come up with the logic , can someone please help me out

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Name, m.Name, f.Name
FROM your_table t
INNER JOIN your_table m ON m.ID = t.Mother
INNER JOIN your_table f ON f.ID = t.Father
```

Use `LEFT JOIN` if you want to include records without `Mother` and/or `Father` nodes:

```
SELECT t.ID, t.Name, ISNULL(m.Name, 'Orphan') Mother, ISNULL(f.Name, 'Orphan') Father
FROM your_table t
LEFT JOIN your_table m ON m.ID = t.Mother
LEFT JOIN your_table f ON f.ID = t.Father
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
select 
    p.id, p.name, p1.name as mother, p2.name as father
from people p
inner join people p1 on p1.id = p.mother
inner join people p2 on p2.id = p.father
```

Answer (score -2):

Select Query

```
SELECT A.*    
FROM tbl A   
    ,tbl M    
    ,tbl F    
WHERE A.Mother = M.ID     
    AND A.Father = F.ID
```

without inner join..

Comment: This is still an INNER JOIN